# pandas: transform based on count of row value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
Gender  Registered
female  1
male    0
female  0
female  1
male    1
male    0
```

df2:

```
Gender
female
female
male
male
```

I want to modify df2, so that there is a new column 'Count' with the count of registered = 1 for corresponding gender values from df1. For example, in df1 there are 2 registered females and 1 registered male. I want to transform the df2 so that the output is as follows:

output:

```
Gender  Count
female  2
female  2
male    1
male    1
```

I tried many things and got close but couldn't make it fully work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `sum` + `map`:

```
v = df1.groupby('Gender').Registered.sum()
df2.assign(Count=df2.Gender.map(v))
```

```
   Gender  Count
0  female      2
1  female      2
2    male      1
3    male      1
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `pd.merge`

```
pd.merge(df2, df1.groupby('Gender', as_index=False).sum())
```

```
    Gender  Registered
0   female  2
1   female  2
2   male    1
3   male    1
```

Comment: I get: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: @Caner can't reproduce, works fine with your sample input. May wanna try to specify to merge `on='Gender'` as argument